# MySQL Update table by matchig values in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table where I store data for different groups and I need to update one group if values in one column are matching.

the table looks like this:

```
prop_id | group_id | value | visible
1       | 1        | 10    | 1
1       | 2        | 10    | 1
1       | 3        | 15    | 1
2       | 1        | 10    | 1
2       | 2        | 10    | 1
2       | 3        | 10    | 1
```

So I want to set the `visible` column to `0` for the `group_id=3` if the values in the `value` column are equal to `group_id=1`. In this case if  `value=10` for both `group_id=1 and group_id=3` than set `visible=0` for `group_id=3`

expected result after update

```
prop_id | group_id | value | visible
1       | 1        | 10    | 1
1       | 2        | 10    | 1
1       | 3        | 15    | 1
2       | 1        | 10    | 1
2       | 2        | 10    | 1
2       | 3        | 10    | 0
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as a `SELECT` first.

Start simple, the rows that we want to update we know are `group_id=3` and `visible=1`, so write a query that gets all of those rows:

```
SELECT g3.value
     , g3.visible 
  FROM mytable g3
 WHERE g3.group_id = 3
   AND g3.visible  = 1
```

We know the rows we want to update are in that set, but there are some additional conditions.

So we extend that.  According to the spec, we need to find out if there are any matching `group_id=1` rows that are `visible=1`  (matching on `value`).

We can do that check either with an `EXISTS` correlated subquery, or we can use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT g3.group_id
     , g3.value
     , g3.visible
  FROM mytable g3
 WHERE g3.group_id = 3
   AND g3.visible  = 1
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable g1
                 WHERE g1.group_id = 1
                   AND g1.visible  = 1
                   AND g1.value    = g3.value 
              )
```

*-or-*

```
SELECT g3.group_id
     , g3.value
     , g3.visible
  FROM mytable g3
  JOIN mytable g1 
    ON g1.group_id = 1
   AND g1.visible  = 1 
   AND g1.value    = g3.value
 WHERE g3.group_id = 3
   AND g3.visible  = 1
```

Verify the query is returning the rows we want to update, under the specific conditions. (It is much easier to verify the results of a `SELECT` statement, and adjust as necessary, than it is an `UPDATE` statement.)

Once we have a `SELECT` query working and verified (returning the rows we want to update) we can convert it into an `UPDATE` statement.  Replace the `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE` and add a `SET` clause that is returning the rows

```
UPDATE mytable g3
  JOIN mytable g1 
    ON g1.group_id = 1
   AND g1.visible  = 1
   AND g1.value    = g3.value

   SET g3.visible  = 0 

 WHERE g3.group_id = 3
   AND g3.visible  = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Works perfectly.

Comment: i use a pattern i call "step wise refinement" when i develop complex SQL. start simple, and get that working. then modify it, and get that working. when we get to a point that's not working, we can back up to what was... makes it easier to figure out why something isn't working, when we can compare to something that is. i'm just not smart enough to write a complex UPDATE statement in one fell swoop and get it right. i write it as a SELECT first, and then convert to UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Self JOIN` then `UPDATE`

You can try this.

```
UPDATE T t1 
JOIN T t2 on t1.group_id = t2.group_id 
and t1.rop_id<>t2.rop_id and t1.value > t2.value 
SET t2.visible = 0
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f06de/1*